# mongodb add new field after insert and auto increment it

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a collections of documents not yet imported into mongo. As documents are being inserted, I want to add a field to each one of them and this field must be auto-incremented. Is there a way to have this logic inside mongodb ?

Example:

```
// docs to insert
{
    _id: id0,
    name: "toto"
}
{
    _id: id1,
    name: "foo"
}

// docs after insertion
{
    _id: id0,
    name: "toto",
    incremental_id: 0
}
{
    _id: id1,
    name: "foo",
    incremental_id: 1
}
```

Currently I am doing this externally with python, however, I would like to achieve the same functionality from within mongo.

Comment: Maybe try here? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_autoincrement_sequence.htm

Comment: I have looked at similar tutorials previously. They assume that the field to be incremented is already in the documents. While in my case, it won't.